# How to use TYPE_BYTE_GRAY to efficiently create a grayscale bufferedimage using AWT

Tags: java, awt, bufferedimage

I need to create a grayscale image from data in an nio ShortBuffer.  I have a function that maps the data in the ShortBuffer to unsigned byte but is in an int (easily changed).  The method I found uses an RGB plus transparency color model and appears to be quite inefficent.  i have not been able to see how to apply the TYPE_BYTE_GRAY and modify the code.  i'm new to Java.  Here's my code:

```
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    final BufferedImage image;
    int[] iArray = {0, 0, 0, 255};  //  pixel

    image = (BufferedImage) createImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    WritableRaster raster = image.getRaster();
    sBuf.rewind();  // nio ShortBuffer
    for (int row = 0; row < HEIGHT; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < WIDTH; col++) {
            int v = stats.mapPix(sBuf.get());  // map short to byte
            iArray[0] = v;  // RGBT
            iArray[1] = v;  
            iArray[2] = v;
            raster.setPixel(col, row, iArray);
        }
    }
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
}
```

TIA
Nate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach would be to create the [`BufferedImage`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) by writing to the raster as you are doing now. Once you have the [`BufferedImage`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html), you can convert it to `TYPE_BYTE_GRAY` using the [`filter()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/ColorConvertOp.html#filter%28java.awt.image.BufferedImage,%20java.awt.image.BufferedImage%29) method of [`ColorConvertOp`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/ColorConvertOp.html), as shown in this [example](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.java.programmer/msg/d4c436ab64d4ced4).

Comment: Thanks, I did find out how to create a gray bufferedimage and got it working and put most of the code in paint in a method.  My program now is much like yours except that I don't read in a JPEG file.  I see that paint is called twice, is that normal?

Comment: @shellback3: The example reads a JPEG, but your code constructs a `BufferedImage` directly from raw data. I don't see any `paint()` method; you can edit your question to show additional code.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out how to do that - the paint() was elsewhere.  (Now to learn how to print a short as an unsigned short - it never ends).  I will get my data directly from a device (or saved in a file) as a sequence of bytes, probably in a bytebuffer.

Comment: A related example using icons is shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12228640/230513).

Answer (score 5):

Insted of using a [ColorConvertOp](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/ColorConvertOp.html), you could simply create a new gray scale [BufferedImage](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) and paint the original colored image onto it:

```
public static BufferedImage convertToGrayScale(BufferedImage image) {
  BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(
            image.getWidth(),
            image.getHeight(),
            BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
  Graphics g = result.getGraphics();
  g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
  g.dispose();
  return result;
}
```

This should perform significantly faster and give better results than using the filter() method.

A great tuturial (including instruction on how to use a [GrayFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/GrayFilter.html)) can be found here: http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorial/Convert-a-Color-Image-to-a-Gray-Scale-Image-in-Java/33347

Comment: Thanks, this appears similar to what I finally found but I've not looked at that code for some time.