# Open an image in two internalFrames, changing one to grayscale

Tags: java, swing, desktop-application, jinternalframe, grayscale

I have created a desktop application where I can open the same image in two `internalFrame`s. I need to change one of those images to grayscale within the application.

My attempt to do this is shown below. When I click the button in my file menu, I need one internal frame image to be the original image and the other one to be grayscale.

```
GuiPanelImage(File fileName) {
     width = GuiPanelImage.WINDOW_WIDTH;

     height = GuiPanelImage.WINDOW_HEIGHT;

    try {
        BufferedImage inputImage = ImageIO.read(fileName); 

        outputImage = new BufferedImage(inputImage.getWidth(),
          inputImage.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
// I can replace .TYPE_INT_ARGB with .TYPE_BYTE_GRAY to convert to grayscale

        picture = new ImageIcon(fileName.getPath());

        Graphics2D g2d = ( Graphics2D) outputImage.createGraphics();

        g2d.drawImage(inputImage, 0, 0, null); 
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GuiPanelImage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,
          null, ex);
    }             
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you just do the following?

```
outputImage1 = new BufferedImage(inputImage.getWidth(), inputImage.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
outputImage2 = new BufferedImage(inputImage.getWidth(), inputImage.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
```

Comment: Yes MR Torgamus i did that part before, just the way you have posted these syntax ; but didnt work just becuse  i got no idea how to call outputImage2 in loadActionPerformed code here is the code

Answer (score 1):

[`PictureFrame`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8090328/230513) illustrates how to display a picture in a `JInternalFrame`.

[image: internal frame]

[`ColorConvertOp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/ColorConvertOp.html) is illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12228640/230513) and compared to a disabled image [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14360103/230513).

[image: gray icons]

Answer (score 0):

try raster functions  for scanning the input and create and output directory for it