# Images Not Updating In Swing

Tags: java, image, swing, repaint, imageicon

I'm having a problem updating an Image in my GUI. Everything besides these methods is coded correctly because the Image appears when I write the code (from the "setImage" method below) in the initilize of the GUI.

I'm trying to get methods to update the image when a button is clicked. However, when the button is clicked, nothing changes. The method calls are correctly written in the MouseListener. All JLabels / Images are declared private so I can call them in the methods.

```
public void setImage(String path) {

    //path = "imageName.png"
    removeImageLabel();
    try {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    imageLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));
    imagePanel.add(imageLabel);
    imagePanel.repaint();
}

public void removeImageLabel() { //removes the current image from the GUI
    imagePanel.remove(imageLabel);
}
```

I have other methods that set elements based on button clicks, but this one doesn't seem to work. No error is thrown, but nothing is updated. What is wrong?

*Note: I have added a println() to the method and it is called.*

**NEW:** *I added an image in the creation of the GUI and it displays, but it is never removed when the methods are called.*

Comment: Have you tried adding some `System.out.println()` in your `setImage` method to see if it was called ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of *replacing* the entire image component, consider *updating* the component's image in place, as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5129757/230513), or *updating* the label's icon in place, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12228640/230513).

Answer (score 0):

call `validate()` instead of `repaint()`