# how to auto change image in java swing?

Tags: java, swing, imageicon, timertask

Hi i am creating a java desktop application where i want  to  show image and i want that all image should change in every 5 sec automatically  i do not know how to do this

here is my code

```
public class ImageGallery extends JFrame
{
    private ImageIcon myImage1 = new ImageIcon ("E:\\SOFTWARE\\TrainPIS\\res\\drawable\\yellow.png");
    private ImageIcon myImage2 = new ImageIcon ("E:\\SOFTWARE\\TrainPIS\\res\\drawable\\d.jpg");
    private ImageIcon myImage3 = new ImageIcon ("E:\\SOFTWARE\\TrainPIS\\res\\drawable\\e.jpg");
    private ImageIcon myImage4 = new ImageIcon ("E:\\SOFTWARE\\TrainPIS\\res\\drawable\f.jpg");
    JPanel ImageGallery = new JPanel();
    private ImageIcon[] myImages = new ImageIcon[4];
    private int curImageIndex=0;

    public ImageGallery ()
        {   
            ImageGallery.add(new JLabel (myImage1));
            myImages[0]=myImage1;
            myImages[1]=myImage2;
            myImages[2]=myImage3;
            myImages[3]=myImage4;

            add(ImageGallery, BorderLayout.NORTH);

            JButton PREVIOUS = new JButton ("Previous");

            JButton NEXT = new JButton ("Next");

            JPanel Menu = new JPanel();
            Menu.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,4));
            Menu.add(PREVIOUS);

            Menu.add(NEXT);

            add(Menu, BorderLayout.SOUTH);



        }
```

How can i achieve this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Step 1) create an `Image[]`. Step 2) store a current index. Step 3) learn how to use a [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html). Step 4) profit.

Answer (score 4):

In this example, a `List<JLabel>` holds each image selected from a `List<Icon>`. At each step of a `javax.swing.Timer`, the  list of images is shuffled, and each image is assigned to a label.

[image]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

/**
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/22423511/230513
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12228640/230513
 */
public class ImageShuffle extends JPanel {

    private List<Icon> list = new ArrayList<Icon>();
    private List<JLabel> labels = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
    private Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            update();
        }
    });

    public ImageShuffle() {
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        list.add(UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon"));
        list.add(UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.informationIcon"));
        list.add(UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.warningIcon"));
        list.add(UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.questionIcon"));
        for (Icon icon : list) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
            labels.add(label);
            this.add(label);
        }
        timer.start();
    }

    private void update() {
        Collections.shuffle(list);
        int index = 0;
        for (JLabel label : labels) {
            label.setIcon(list.get(index++));
        }
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("ImageShuffle");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(this);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ImageShuffle().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replay but it does not meet with my need

Comment: How can i add my own images

Comment: `list.add(new ImageIcon("E:\\…\\yellow.png"))`

Comment: i want to create single jlabel and want to suffle  image ina every 5 sec on single jlabel

Comment: Instead of a `List<JLabel>`, use a single `JLabel`; after `shuffle()`, invoke `label.setIcon(list.get(0))`

Comment: for (JLabel label : labels) {
            label.setIcon(list.get(index++));
        }

Comment: in place of List<JLabel> i used

Comment: private JLabel labels = new JLabel();

Comment: Please update your question with an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows your current approach.

Answer (score 1):

one way of achieving your goal is setting a swing.Timer to notify its action listeners every 5 seconds, set your class to be the listener for the timer and implement the actionListener interface by having an actionPerformed method which will change all images using their setImage method. the code should look like this:

```
public class ImageGallery extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
Timer timer;

public ImageGallery() {
    timer = new Timer(5000, this);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == timer) {
        for (int i=0; i<vectorOfImages.size(); i++) {
            vectorOfImages.get(i).setImage(AnotherImage);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: sorry to ask but what is Another Image

Comment: that not an object or anything :)
i was just trying to say that you should put the image you want to change to in there

Comment: what is  what is vectorofimages.sze();

Comment: assuming you have a large number of imageIcons you probably would choose to put them inside an array or vector, in that case you should change every imageIcon on that vector.. sze was supposed to be size ill fix that now..

Comment: i created array o imageicon  and i run loo .lenth it is not working

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49814/discussion-between-tom-and-user3419449)