# How to image shuffle on jlabel?

Tags: java, swing, timer, imageicon

I am creating a  Java desktop application  where I want to shuffle image in every 3 sec. I am able to do this, but problem is that I want to use only single `JLabel` where all image shuffle in every 3 sec and I have code for multiple `JLabel`

Here is the code I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22423511/230513). I want to use only single `JLabel`. How can I achieve this?

```
/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22423511/230513
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12228640/230513
 */
public class ImageShuffle extends JPanel {

    private List<Icon> list = new ArrayList<Icon>();
    private List<JLabel> labels = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
    private Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            update();
        }
    });

    public ImageShuffle() {
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        list.add(UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon"));
        list.add(UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.informationIcon"));
        list.add(UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.warningIcon"));
        list.add(UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.questionIcon"));
        for (Icon icon : list) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
            labels.add(label);
            this.add(label);
        }
        timer.start();
    }

    private void update() {
        Collections.shuffle(list);
        int index = 0;
        for (JLabel label : labels) {
            label.setIcon(list.get(index++));
        }
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("ImageShuffle");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(this);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ImageShuffle().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Note [*attribution required*](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [variation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22616636/230513) of the [original example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22423511/230513) has some unfortunate (but perhaps instructive) problems:

- A new instance of `Random` is created at each iteration; only one is required.
- The expression `r.nextInt(3) + 1` never selects the first or last element of the `list`.
- The use of numeric literals may cause the program to fail if the size of the `list` changes.

Instead, `shuffle()` the `list` and choose the first element.

```
private void update() {
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    label.setIcon(list.get(0));
}
```

As tested:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22631012/230513
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22423511/230513
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12228640/230513
 */
public class ImageShuffle extends JPanel {

    private List<Icon> list = new ArrayList<Icon>();
    private JLabel label = new JLabel();
    private Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            update();
        }
    });

    public ImageShuffle() {
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        list.add(UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon"));
        list.add(UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.informationIcon"));
        list.add(UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.warningIcon"));
        list.add(UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.questionIcon"));
        label.setIcon(UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.informationIcon"));

        timer.start();
    }

    private void update() {
        Collections.shuffle(list);
        label.setIcon(list.get(0));
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("ImageShuffle");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(this);
        f.add(label);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ImageShuffle().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22626212/2587435). You been beat to it ;-) OP's fault though for double posting.

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/22616636/318599
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/22423511/230513
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12228640/230513
 */
public class ImageShuffle extends JPanel {

   private List<Icon> list = new ArrayList<Icon>();
   private List<JLabel> labels = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
   private JLabel label = new JLabel();
   private Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

      @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        update();
       }
   });

   public ImageShuffle() {
       this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));
       list.add(UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon"));
       list.add(UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.informationIcon"));
       list.add(UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.warningIcon"));
       list.add(UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.questionIcon"));
       label.setIcon(UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.informationIcon"));

       timer.start();
   }

   private void update() {

    Random r=new Random();
    int i1=(r.nextInt(3) +1);

    label.setIcon(list.get(i1));
}

private void display() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("ImageShuffle");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.add(this);
    f.add(label);
    f.pack();
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

           @Override
          public void run() {
              new ImageShuffle().display();
           }
       });
   }
 }
```

Comment: i am waiting for replay

Comment: I have done the changes based on the code user3456343 wrote in his question. I honestly haven't read or copied anything from that post

Comment: I see; I've added a citation for your variation to the top of the comment.