# How to Shuffle image in sequence?

Tags: java, swing, timer, imageicon

I am trying to make  Java desktop application where i want to make auto image shuffle i am able to do this but problem is that it is not shuffling all  image which i gave  i want to shuffle all image 
how can i achieve this

Here is some code I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22423511/230513):

```
/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22423511/230513
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12228640/230513
 */
public class ImageShuffle extends JPanel {

   private List<Icon> list = new ArrayList<Icon>();

   private JLabel label = new JLabel();
   private Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

      @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        update();
       }
   });

   public ImageShuffle() {
       this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));

      list.add(new ImageIcon("E:\\SOFTWARE\\TrainPIS\\res\\drawable\\e.jpg"));
    list.add(new ImageIcon("E:\\SOFTWARE\\TrainPIS\\res\\drawable\\d.jpg"));
    list.add(new ImageIcon("E:\\SOFTWARE\\TrainPIS\\res\\drawable\\yellow.png"));
      list.add(new ImageIcon("E:\\SOFTWARE\\TrainPIS\\res\\drawable\\f.jpg"));
         //   list.add(new ImageIcon("E:\\SOFTWARE\\TrainPIS\\res\\drawable\\yellow.jpg"));
       //label.setIcon(UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.informationIcon"));

       timer.start();
   }

   private void update() {

    Random r=new Random();
    int i1=(r.nextInt(3) +1);

    label.setIcon(list.get(i1));
}

private void display() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("ImageShuffle");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.add(this);
    f.add(label);
    f.pack();
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

           @Override
          public void run() {
              new ImageShuffle().display();
           }
       });
   }
 }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519736/random-shuffling-of-an-array

Comment: You could use [`Collections.shuffle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) and grab the first element of the list...

Comment: how can i use this can you explain little bit

Comment: @user3456343, the implementation and explanation is very much self-explanatory in the linked question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by creating a shuffled list...

```
private List<Icon> list = new ArrayList<Icon>();
private List<Icon> shuffled;

//...

list.add(new ImageIcon("E:\\SOFTWARE\\TrainPIS\\res\\drawable\\e.jpg"));
list.add(new ImageIcon("E:\\SOFTWARE\\TrainPIS\\res\\drawable\\d.jpg"));
list.add(new ImageIcon("E:\\SOFTWARE\\TrainPIS\\res\\drawable\\yellow.png"));
list.add(new ImageIcon("E:\\SOFTWARE\\TrainPIS\\res\\drawable\\f.jpg"));

shuffled = new ArrayList<Icon>();
update();
```

Each time your timer ticks and calls `actionPerformed`, pop the first element of the `shuffled` list until nothing is left...

```
 if (shuffled.isEmpty()) {
    shuffled.addAll(list);
    // Prevent the current image from been selected next...
    shuffled.remove(label.getIcon());
    Collections.shuffle(shuffled);
 }

 Icon icon = shuffled.remove(0);
 label.setIcon(icon);
```

This will remove the possibility of an image been allowed to be displayed multiple times in a row.  Your random value calculation should have been more like `int i1 = (r.nextInt(list.size()));` anyway...

**Notes:**

`ImageShuffle` doesn't need to extend from `JPanel`, you not adding anything to it.  This means you can get rid of `this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));` and `f.add(this);` and the program should still run